# form-3 component not rerendering anything even though :component-did-update is called

Tags: clojurescript, reagent

I have the following code to test out form-3 components:

```
(defn inner [data]
  (reagent/create-class
   {:display-name "Counter"

    :component-did-mount (fn []
                           (js/console.log "Initialized")
                           [:h1 "Initialized! " data])


    :component-did-update (fn [this _]
                            (let [[_ data] (reagent/argv this)]
                              (js/console.log (str "Updated " data))
                              [:div (str "My clicks " data)]))

    :reagent-render (fn [] [:div (str "My clicks " data)])}))
```

I am able to successfully trigger both the `:component-did-mount` and the `:component-did-update` as there is the expected output in the console log. However, neither of the two functions actually change anything on the page. It just shows the initial state of `[:div (str "My clicks " data)]` the whole time.

What am I doing wrong? Ps. I have read the [reagent docs](https://github.com/reagent-project/reagent/blob/master/doc/CreatingReagentComponents.md) and the [purelyfunctional guide](https://purelyfunctional.tv/guide/re-frame-lifecycle/#component-did-update).

Comment: Do I need to fetch the appropriate dom-node in component-did-update and change it? I am new to web-stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to [repeat the parameters](https://github.com/reagent-project/reagent/blob/master/doc/CreatingReagentComponents.md#form-3-a-class-with-life-cycle-methods) in the `:reagent-render` function:

```
(fn [data] [:div (str "My clicks " data)])
```

Comment: Thanks. Since the console fired logging info I thought I was doing that correctly enough. I guess repeat means have exactly the same names, not just the same arity. Perhaps that could be emphasized in the docs :) (Come to think of it I also missed the arity :flushed)